# Can I make sentence with "scramble" in this way?

Tags: word-usage

In the dictionary, *scrambling* means that compete for something.

so ,Can i make the sentence with ''scramble'' in this way....

1. I scramble for life.
2. Mr. Alex is scrambling as vice president candidate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Scramble" means a disorganised and frantic competition for something.  You can imagine people competing for something on the ground, everyone trying to grab it.

> The rugby ball was on the ground and both sides scrambled for it.

So if you mean "a frantic and desperate struggle for life" sentence 1. is possible.

If you said "Alex and Jo are scrambling for the final votes in the tight vice presidential race", it has the right sense.  But you can't use it to mean "Alex is a candidate"  It has to mean "disorganised and frantic competition"